# сворачивание вертикального меню

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

Меню развёртывается при наведении на кнопку и сворачивается при  событии MouseLeave на гриде.  Если меню не развернуть и убрать курсор с грида, меню откроется и будет закрываться. Увидев код я думаю вы поймёте о чём я говорю. Какими ещё способами можно это реализовать, с использование MouseLeave?

Анимация сворачивания/разворота меню.

```
<Window.Resources>        
    <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="GridHeaderMenu">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="30"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="80"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CloseMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" 
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="GridHeaderMenu">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="80"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="30"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

Триггеры:

```
<Window.Triggers>        
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter" SourceName="imgOpenMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseLeave" SourceName="GridHeaderMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>        
</Window.Triggers>
```

Меню:убрал в коде лишнее, для компактности.

```
            <Grid Name="GridHeaderMenu" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#FFEEE9E8" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Height="30" Width="150"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  Margin=" 0, 50,10,0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image/>
                        <Image/>
                        <Image/>
                        <Image/>
                        <Image/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" Margin="0, 10">
                        <Image/>
                        <Image/>
                        <Image/>
                        <Image/> 
                    </StackPanel>

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно анимацию делать? Вот допустим анимация закрытия `<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="GridHeaderMenu" Duration="0:0:0.3" To="30" />`, анимация открытия будет той же, только с `To="80"`. И это уже сделает в разы лучше, ибо анимация будет стартовать с того Height, который сейчас у вашего объекта, а не с нуля. Ну или убрать первый кадр анимации (`EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"`). Вообще кстати не советую анимировать Height, ибо контенту внутри будет плохо...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за коммент. Прям в точку) А почему будет "плохо"? Весь контент на месте, где и должен быть. Какие подводные ожидают?

Comment: Я очень долго боролся с выезжающим меню сбоку, а именно с [этим](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjaum.gif) эффектом. Как видите, весь контент начинает вести себя не очень красиво, приходилось убирать через `Margin` или что то на подобие. С Изменением высоты объекта, я лично [не смог](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHFMD.gif) этот эффект воспроизвести, но уверен, что он там есть и с каким нибудь изображением или еще каким либо элементом зависящим от высоты - будет то же самое, что и с изменением ширины.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Буду иметь ввиду. Спасибо ещё раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если меню не развернуть и убрать курсор с грида, меню откроется и будет закрываться.

Все это потому, что вы явно пишете высоту стартовой точки, уберите все нулевые кадры (`<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="..."/>`), тогда ваша анимация будет стартовать с текущего значения `Height`.

---

Вообще вы как то странно написали анимацию, может стоит переписать на что то в этом духе?

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                 Storyboard.TargetName="GridHeaderMenu" 
                 Duration="0:0:0.3" To="30" />
```

И тут тоже как видите не стоит `From` значения, всего лишь `To`.